# Javascript If else statement only returns 'else'

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to sync subtitles with the video tag in HTML and I'm using for loop to iterate on this JSON object :

```js
var sub_info = [
    {"id": 10, "start": "3.920", "end": "6.840", "text": "subtitle text" },
    {"id": 11, "start": "7.500", "end": "10.820", "text": "sample sub text"},
]
```

and this is the for loop I've written for this purpose :

```js
function myFunc() {
    for (var info of sub_info) {
        if( videoPlayer.currentTime >= info.start && videoPlayer.currentTime <= info.end ) {
            subtitles.innerHTML = info.text
        } else {
            subtitles.innerHTML = " "
        }
    }
}
```

when I only write if it works fine but the problem is that I don't want any subtitles to be shown while there is no conversation.
and when I add else it only returns else.

I've also tried `subtitles.innerHTML = " "` outside of the for loop and still, it doesn't work.

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You are comparing a number with strings

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I'm not sure that's it. `4.2 >= '4.1' // true` and `7.500 >= '10.820' // false`

Comment: Also, you seem to be assigning to the same property (`subtitles.innerHTML`) repeatedly in a loop. Only the last value you assign will be remembered. If you want multiple values, you have to assign to multiple targets, use an array, use concatenation (on a variable and then assign once after the loop), etc.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz that should be fine `"17.500" < 2` is `false` and `"17.500" < 18` is `true`. The values are coerced to numbers.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz I know that, but if that's the case, why is it working fine without the else statement?

Comment: @VLAZ Yup, you're right. Sorry.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks for the explanation, but I didn't understand it completely, could you include some code too?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are testing agains all subtitles each time so it will only really work for the last subtitle.

Instead of a loop where you update the subtitle, do a [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the active subtitle and if there is one then update. If not then clear.

something like

```js
function myFunc() {
  const activeSubtitle = sub_info.find(
    (sub) =>
      parseFloat(sub.start) <= videoPlayer.currentTime &&
      parseFloat(sub.end) >= videoPlayer.currentTime
  );
  if (activeSubtitle) {
    subtitles.innerHTML = activeSubtitle.text;
  } else {
    subtitles.innerHTML = " ";
  }
}
```